# Input variable for connecting to a specified socket.io server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, client

So I am making an application based off of Socket.io and I am working on my app starting up and asking for a server ip which to connect to as a input variable but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work. Here's the code:

```
const chalk = require('chalk').constructor({ enabled: true, level: 3 });;

const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

    rl.question(`Please type in Server CURL/IP\n\n `, (serverip) => {
    id = serverip;
    var socket = io(serverip);

    });

var id = "";
var buffer = "";


function chat(){
    rl.question(chalk.magenta("» "), (answer) => {
        buffer = `${chalk.cyan(id)} : ${chalk.blue(answer)}`;
        socket.emit("message", buffer);
        chat();
    });
}

socket.on('connect', () => {

    rl.question(`What is your name?\n\n `, (answer) => {
            socket.emit("message", `${chalk.green(answer)} has joined the chat`);
            id = answer;
            chat();

    });

    socket.on('msg', function(data){
        if(buffer!=data){
            console.log("\n" + data);
            chat();
        }
    });

})
```

If anyone could help that'd be amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're hitting the asynchronous nature of Javascript here. `readline.question()` returns immediately. When your user finishes answering its question it calls its callback.
So, the second of your two `var socket = io()` lines, the one mentioning `server`, runs before `server` is defined.

You must do more work in the callback from `readline.question()` and less work at your outer level.

**Edit** I'll try to point you in the right direction. Still, you really do need to read up on Javascript and how callbacks are totally vital to its flow of control.

This is not, repeat not, debugged.

```
rl.question(`Please type in Server CURL/IP\n\n `, (serverip) => {
  /* only in the this callback function you have access to socket */
  var socket = io(serverip);

  /* use socket here to set up your operations. */
  socket.on('connect', () => {
    rl.question(`What is your name?\n\n `, (answer) => {
      socket.emit("message", `${chalk.green(answer)} has joined the chat`);
      id = answer;
      chat(socket);
    });
  });

  socket.on('msg', function(data){
    if(buffer!=data){
      console.log("\n" + data);
      chat(socket);
    }
  });
});

/* you can use socket in a function defined at the top level
 * if you pass it to that function as a parameter
 */
function chat(socket) {
  rl.question(chalk.magenta("» "), (answer) => {
      buffer = `${chalk.cyan(id)} : ${chalk.blue(answer)}`;
      socket.emit("message", buffer);
      chat(socket);
    });
}
```

Learning a lot about callbacks, promises, and Javascript's async / await is in your future.

Comment: So I deleted the second line that determine the server connection because I just realized that 2 exist. I am also kind of confused what the problem is still, I understand what your saying just I am unsure what I need to do to fix this. Bare with me here haha.

Comment: update: I realized that I need the ```var socket = io(serverip);``` line to run after the question is answered but for some reason it won't let the user answer the question before the error breaks out. It's right on the tip of my tongue this is starting to hurt my head. I don't know much about async on javascript, I do know async on python though. How can I stop the question from calling back?

Comment: The only way to *stop the question from calling  back* is to give it an empty callback function. But then you will have no way to get your user's answer to the question. Please see my edit to my answer.

Comment: Ah, thank you for your amazing knowledge! I will definitely read a bunch more about callbacks, seems interesting :D